# sending midi to software using arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, midi

Friends Here is what i want to ask.

I have a midi keyboard that is casio cps7. Its an old model so its not a USB midi keyboard. 
I use it with a cheap midi to usb cable.
I just wanted to use my arduino to act like a midi to USB adapter. So, i can use my midi keyboard with that too.
I found some tutorials that uses this arduino like usb serial device. And there is also a code for it. The code itself has a command to play midi notes.
We receive serial signals from arduino and convert them into midi (by using another software that is serial midi converter, there is also virtual midi port for it which is midi-yoke). Thats how i used my arduino board once but the program code for it (what i installed) plays its own notes. I just want to send my midi out (from my keyboard casio cps7) to pc as serial via arduino. Thanks

I hope you guys now understand what i wanted to say :)

Comment: You want to do *what*? What keyboard? Which Arduino? Do you have MIDI conversion hardware? `I think the change should be in the program code` - what code? `I already have installed midi yoke` - what yoke? Link? `I already have installed ... serial midi coverter in pc` - what midi converter? Link? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: So you want to connect the Uno's first UART to the PC, and the second UART to the keyboard, and let the Uno act as a bridge?

Comment: Yes u got that right. I want to use arduino uno to act like interface to pc over usb for my 5pin midi out of my casio cps7 keyboard